# Как функцией LISTAGG вернуть значения без повторений?

Tags: sql, oracle

Пробую воспользоваться функцией `LISTAGG`. Надо получить значения колоннки без повторений.

Возможно ли это без создания дополнительных функций?

```sql
with data (col1, col2, creator) as (
    select 1, 2, 'Smith' from dual union all 
    select 1, 2, 'John'  from dual union all 
    select 1, 3, 'Ajay'  from dual union all 
    select 1, 4, 'Ram'   from dual union all 
    select 1, 5, 'Jack'  from dual 
    )
select '['||listagg (col2, ',') within group (order by col2)||']' res 
from data
```

Нужно получить колонку `col1` и список из колонки `col2` функцией `LISTAGG`.
Получаю `[2,2,3,4,5]`, а желаемый результат `[2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11510870/6571020

Answer (score 3):

```sql
select listagg (col, ',') within group (order by col)
from (
   select distinct col2 col
   from data
) t
```

Если нужно больше колонок, то нечто такое будет решением:

```
select col1, listagg (col2, ',') within group (order by col2)
from (
  select col1, col2, row_number () over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1) as rn
  from data
  order by col1, col2
)
where rn = 1
group by col1;
```

Источник: [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511203/6571020)

Answer (score 3):

В актуальной версии Oracle 19c в `LISTAGG` добавлена опция `DISTINCT`.

[DISTINCT Option for LISTAGG Aggregate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-89203F7C-527E-4C9E-B628-9AE0F955F4A7)

> The `LISTAGG` aggregate function now supports duplicate elimination by using the new `DISTINCT` keyword.

```sql
select col1, listagg (distinct col2, ',') within group (order by col2) res
from data
group by col1;
```

Даст желаемый результат:

```
      COL1 RES       
---------- ----------
         1 2,3,4,5
```